# How to create this custom edittext ? Please help

Tags: java, android, controls

In an application I wish to create an edit text control like shown here http://www.customeuropeanplates.com/images/UK-License-Plate.jpg can anybody please suggest how should this be done? I know this is something easy but I am new to android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 9-patch drawable for the EditText's background (yellow background with black border). You can create 9-patch images with 9-patch tool (draw9patch) that is located under the SDK Tools folder. And then you'll need custom font for the text. Text is aligned to the center of EditText.